# Mailchimp API Gem - To save other merge fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am using MailChimp Gem to add a member to my MailChimp list. The member is getting added with the subscribed status correctly but I am passing the first name, last name, some referral code, and interests as well. But those are not getting set properly. Here is my code.

```
mailchimp1.lists.subscribe("xxxxxxxxx", 
     { email => "srividhya@xxxxxx.com",
       status => "subscribed",
       merge_fields =>  (MMERGE1 = "srividhya", MMERGE2 = "prakash", MMERGE3 = "srip1" ),
       interests  => {24713 => "true"}
     })
```

Not sure what I am missing.
Any pointers would be helpful.
TIA

Answer (score 1):

Here is 2 example of a typical configuration:

```
mailchimp1.lists.subscribe({:id => ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"], 
                            :email => {:email => user.email}, 
                            :merge_vars => {:FNAME => user.first_name, :LNAME => user.last_name}, 
                            :double_optin => false})

mailchimp1.lists.subscribe(MAIL_CHIMP_LIST_ID,
                           # The email field is a struct that can use an
                           #    email address or two MailChimp specific list ids (see API docs)
                           {email: user.email},
                           # Set your merge vars here
                           {'FNAME' => user.first_name, 'LNAME' => user.last_name})
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried this but got this below error. ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..8). Trying multiple options. Fingers crossed.

Comment: I leave another example of typical configuration, hopefully this one if it works, Use the following article as a guide: https://andrew.coffee/blog/how-to-add-subscribers-to-a-mailchimp-list-with-ruby.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mailchimp1.lists.subscribe(
  "xxxxxxxxx", 
  { email: "srividhya@xxxxxx.com" },
  {
       FNAME: "srividhya",
       LNAME: "prakash"
    }
)
```

If you can get this to work, then you can add additional parameters following this reference:

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mailchimp-api/2.0.4/Mailchimp/Lists#subscribe-instance_method